# MYSQL+PHP How to update auto-incremented id when delete row in table?

Tags: php, mysql

```
 $q = "DELETE FROM newfiles WHERE id=$id LIMIT 1;";
 $q .= "SET @i=0;";
 $q .= "UPDATE newfiles SET id=(@i +:=1)";
```

Ex:- I have 6 Rows

**1
2
3
4
5
6**
when i delete Row 4 
i want the row 5 to become 4 and 6 to 5

Comment: Why, though? If I may ask. Seems unnecessary and overly complex.

Comment: Generally a bad idea! if you have dependancy tables without relationship, you will have inconsistency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this is not a good practice. But you can try like this. This will work.

```
$q = "SET @id = $id;";
$q .= "DELETE FROM newfiles WHERE id = @id;";
$q .= "UPDATE newfiles SET id = id-1 WHERE id > @id;";
```